# How to import big amount of data from file to sqlite inside the application (in real-time)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, import, sqlite

I have a big list of words (over 2 millions) in CSV file (size about 35MB).
I wanted to import the CSV file into sqlite3 with index (primiary key).
So I've imported it using sqlite command line tool. The DB has been created and size of the .sqlite file has grown to over 120MB! (50% because of primary key index)

And here we get the problem: if I add this 120MB .sqlite  file to the resources even after compressing to .ipa file it has >60MB. And I'd like if it will be less then 30MB (because of the limitiation through E/3G).

Also because of the size I cannot import it (zipped sqlite file) by a web service (45MB * 1000 download = 45GB! it's my server's half year limit).

So I thought I could do something like this:

1. compress the CSV file with words to ZIP and than the file will have only 7MB file.
2. add ZIP file to resources.
3. in the application I can unzip the file and import data from the unzipped CSV file to sqlite.

But I don't know how to do this. I've tried to do this  :

```
sqlite3_exec(sqlite3_database, ".import mydata.csv mytable", callback, 0, &errMsg);
```

but it doesn't work. The reason for the failure is ".import" is a part of the command line interface and not in the C API.

So I need to know how to import it(unzipped CSV file) to the SQLite file inside app (not during develompent using command line).

Comment: is this related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455606/how-to-import-file-into-sqlite

Comment: nope. I've read it. There is no answer for my question in the case.

Comment: as a site note Ya ? am I right?

Answer (score 2):

If the words that you are inserting are unique you could make the text the primary key.

If you only want to test whether words exist in a set (say for a spell checker), you could use an alternative data structure such as a bloom filter, which only requires 9.6 bits for each word with 1% false positives.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter

Comment: I need the full data, but thx (+1) this is a good idea for future anyway

Answer (score 1):

As FlightOfStairs mentioned depending on the requirements a bloom filter is one solution, if you need the full data another solution is to use a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or [radix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) data structure. You would preprocess your data and build these datastructures and then either put it in sqlite or some other external data format.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to write a CSV parser using NSScanner and insert the rows into the database one by one. That's actually a fairly easy job—you can find a complete CSV parser [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/11/writing-parser-using-nsscanner-csv.html).

Comment: I'm not sure if it's good idea to insert 2+ milions of rows to the database one by one...

Comment: No, it isn't, and it will likely require an unreasonable amount of initialization time. But that's exactly what the command-line utility does.

Comment: Have you considered putting the file on a cloud service like Amazon's S3 and allowing the app to download it from there? That will be quite inexpensive even if you have many downloads (1GB is only $0.15 or so, I believe).