# Convert MySQL file to SQLite database

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I've tried several ways to convert the SQL file found [here](http://wing.comp.nus.edu.sg/SMSCorpus/) into an SQLite file. Ways include [this script](https://gist.github.com/943776) (which produces the table properly in SQLite but empty), [this script](http://www.jbip.net/content/how-convert-mysql-sqlite), and I've tried outputting the data from MySQL as CSV which I then tried to import into SQLite, getting apparently the wrong amount of columns...

Is there no easy way to convert from MySQL to SQLite?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164033/export-a-mysql-database-to-sqlite-database

Comment: I have seen those solutions, they have not helped.