# Recreate MySQL database in SQLite

Tags: mysql, swift, sqlite, xcode6

I have a MySQL database that I would like in SQLite for an app I'm planning to develop.  How would I go about this?  Thanks.

I saw the previous question [Export a MySQL Database to SQLite Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164033/export-a-mysql-database-to-sqlite-database)

However, there was no accepted or definitive solution.  So what would be the best approach to doing this?

**OK, my solution: (hope somebody finds this useful)**

1. Installed DB Browser for SQLite from http://sqlitebrowser.org/
2. I exported the MySQL structure (without data) as SQL.
3. Then cleaned up the SQL according to this link
   http://livecode.byu.edu/database/mysql-sqliteExport.php
4. Then in DB Browser for SQLite imported the cleaned up SQL to create the database and all the tables. I found that DB Browser for SQLite didn't allow importing of CSV data into the already created tables.  So I went to the Apple App Store on my Mac and bought and installed SQLPro for SQLite app ($12 Australian...).
5. In SQLPro for SQLite I opened the SQLite database created in DB
   Browser for SQLite.Then exported each MySQL table as CSV and
   imported those into each existing table in SQLPro for SQLite.
6. Done

Comment: You may or may not be able to easily migrate it.  MySQL has a lot of functionality which SQLite does not have.

Comment: Sounds like it may be best to to recreate from scratch using something like SQLite Database Browser.

Comment: If you have a lot of data already in the MySQL database I'd go for generating an json or XML file and importing that file in the app. Take into consideration that sqlite already has an autoincremented id for each row, as specified here: https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Answer (score 1):

Although I've only used sqlite in an Android environment, I would recommend looking over the following:

- [Documentation and examples](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md)
- [Step-by-step example of usage](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/use-sqlite-database-swift)
- [SQLite vs MySQL vs PostgreSQL](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/sqlite-vs-mysql-vs-postgresql-a-comparison-of-relational-database-management-systems)

Keep in mind that  sqlite is a stripped-down version of mysql and has a lot of features missing. For example, while altering an table you may only rename or add new columns, but you may not delete the existing columns. Have a look at the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/docs.html) for more specific details that may apply to your specific implementation.

You may find all the limitations here: [Sqlite limitations](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)