# Import of .sql dump files to data frames

Tags: mysql, r

I want to import a local sql dump-file as n `data.frames`, that can be downloaded [here](http://www.ahschulz.de/pub/R/data/enron-mysqldump_v5.sql.gz) (170 MB) from http://www.ahschulz.de/enron-email-data/, into my R workspace.

*Before you ask: "Why won't you download the .Rdata file?" - Proxy problems at my location*

I researched for solutions but couldn't find any and I don't want do create my own database locally with a new server.

Any suggestions for importing? Packages or anything? Thanks!

Comment: I think you will probably need MySQL in some way or form to convert those dump files to another format, e.g. CSV.  These files were intended to import into MySQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I wonder if it's possible to convert MySQL to sqlite, which can be used in R with far less pain than the rest of SQL databases.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik You might be on to something: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164033/export-a-mysql-database-to-sqlite-database

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen only two indirect dependencies, sweet.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have been down that road before... Unless the data is pretty simple don't try it - none of the scripts I found handled every situation.  Just install mySQL server and be done with it.  My advice to the questioner is to download the file at another location in the Rdata format.

Comment: @IanWesley Yes, if I only had the SQL dump files I would just install MySQL and go from there.  Or, as you said, get the `.RData` files from a non blocked location.  When asked to build a car using a boat, the answers tend to get stretched pretty thin.