# Transferring data from MySQL to SQLite fails

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I want to transfer the model of my database and all containing information from MySQL to SQLite. For this purpose I used the mysqldump tool and generated a sql script file.
Then I tried to import this file into my SQLite database and ran in many errors. F.e. there are commands like "KEY", "COMMENT", "LOCK TABLES", "UNLOCK TABLES" or "ON UPDATE" which seems not be supported.
is there any way to generate SQLite conform scripts or is there a possibiility to automatically convert the script later?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164033/export-a-mysql-database-to-sqlite-database

Comment: just google for "mysql to sqlite converter" - like this one - https://gist.github.com/esperlu/943776